# Raising user defined exception when connecting to sqlite

Tags: python, exception

Let's say that I want to connect to database but getting an error on connect. In most of examples what I found people catch basic Error exception. But it also will catch any other mistake. So, the question is, what should I do to raise different user defined exceptions? In other words, how to throw user defined exception instead of predefined exception?

Comment: Catch the exception and throw your own exception.

Comment: You should cascade the errors, [from most specific to most general](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), and in the except block of, say, `ValueError` you raise `MyCustomValueError` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
class MySpecificException(Exception):
    print('Handle exception here:')

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('error text')
    raise MySpecificException('SpecificException')
```